# Implementing flood fill in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, paint

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of Paint, and for this I need to make a filling. Can anyone tell how to use PyQt5 to find out the color of a pixel, and use the width search to find similar pixels. And then change all these pixels to a new color. Just in tkinter for this were getpixel and putpixel. I'm wondering if PyQt5 does this. If there is, then I ask to show some example of the implementation of this.

P.s. You can without looking for pixels, just show how to take and replace pixels.

P.s.s.  I apologize for my English, if something is wrong с:

Comment: This is a bit too broad. It also appears you are just asking someone to write the code for you, but it may be a slight language barrier preventing me from understanding. But it would be best to show what you have tried and where you are having problems.

Comment: @mrunion I want to study the analogues of putpixel and getpixel from tkinter. Is there anyway, and how do they work. You can reset the reference to information. I just could not find it. If necessary, I can, for example, send an example from tkinter, so that it is clear what I mean.

Comment: You can use `.pixel` and `pixelColor` on a `QImage` but it is rather slow. I've posted a working example which is quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [an implementation of a Paint program here](https://github.com/mfitzp/15-minute-apps/blob/master/paint/paint.py) which includes an example of a flood fill.

Unfortunately, it's a little more complicated than you might imagine. Reading a pixel from a `QImage` in Qt is possible you can do it as follows —

```
QImage.pixel(x, y)       # returns a QRgb object
QImage.pixelColor(x, y)  # returns a QColor object
```

#### Basic algorithm

The basic Forest Fire fill algorithm using `QImage.pixel(x,y)` is shown below. We start by converting our pixmap to a `QImage` (if neccessary).

```
    image = self.pixmap().toImage()
    w, h = image.width(), image.height()
    x, y = e.x(), e.y()

    # Get our target color from origin.
    target_color = image.pixel(x,y)
```

Then we define a function which, for a given position looks at all surrounding positions — if they haven't been looked at yet — and tests whether it is a *hit* or a *miss*. If it's a hit, we store that pixel to fill later.

```
    def get_cardinal_points(have_seen, center_pos):
        points = []
        cx, cy = center_pos
        for x, y in [(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)]:
            xx, yy = cx + x, cy + y
            if (xx >= 0 and xx < w and
                yy >= 0 and yy < h and
                (xx, yy) not in have_seen):

                points.append((xx, yy))
                have_seen.add((xx, yy))

        return points
```

To perform the fill we create a `QPainter` to write to our original pixmap. Then, starting at our initial `x,y` we iterate, checking cardinal points, and — if we have a match — pushing those new squares onto our queue. We fill any matching points as we go.

```
    # Now perform the search and fill.
    p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
    p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color))

    have_seen = set()
    queue = [(x, y)]

    while queue:
        x, y = queue.pop()
        if image.pixel(x, y) == target_color:
            p.drawPoint(QPoint(x, y))
            queue.extend(get_cardinal_points(have_seen, (x, y)))

    self.update()
```

#### Performance

The `QImage.pixel()` can be slow, so the above implementation reading/writing directly on the `QImage` isn't really feasible for very large images. After that point it will start to take > a few seconds to fill the area.

The solution I've used is to convert the area to be filled into `bytes`. There are 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA). This gives us a data structure that's far quicker to interact with.

```
    image = self.pixmap().toImage() # Convert to image if you have a QPixmap
    w, h = image.width(), image.height()
    s = image.bits().asstring(w * h * 4)
```

Next we need to find our current location's 3-byte (RGB) value. With our data structure, we create a custom function to retrieve our hit/miss bytes.

```
    # Lookup the 3-byte value at a given location.
    def get_pixel(x, y):
        i = (x + (y * w)) * 4
        return s[i:i+3]

    x, y = e.x(), e.y()
    target_color = get_pixel(x, y)
```

The actual loop to perform the search for all points in our input and write them out to the `QPixmap` if we find a match.

```
    # Now perform the search and fill.
    p = QPainter(self.pixmap())
    p.setPen(QPen(self.active_color))

    have_seen = set()
    queue = [(x, y)]

    while queue:
        x, y = queue.pop()
        if get_pixel(x, y) == target_color:
            p.drawPoint(QPoint(x, y))
            queue.extend(get_cardinal_points(have_seen, (x, y)))

    self.update()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this tutorial! I went to try to do something like this in my code с: